# PHP Function with iCal Parser slowing down page load time

Tags: php, performance, function, return, icalendar

I have this function which uses the iCal parser by Martin Thoma [Github Link Here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/ics-parser/)

This function is performing very slowly, about 12 seconds to get the event dates from the iCal calendars.

How can I improve the function process?

The exclusions variable is then outputted in my Javascript loading at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

I've tried the page without this function and it loads very quick so I've narrowed it down to this function.

It could be I'm reusing the iCal class incorrectly but I don't know a way around this.

Please help

```
function process_ical($airbnb_ical_link,$google_ical_link,$booking_dot_com_ical_link,$homeaway_ical_link) {

    require 'class.iCalReader.php';

    $exclusions = '"2019-01-01"';

    if ($airbnb_ical_link != '') {

        $ical   = new ICal($airbnb_ical_link);
        $events = $ical->events();

        if (is_array($events) || is_object($events)) {

            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $formatedStart = $ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTSTART']);
                $formatedEnd = $ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTEND']);
                $str1 = date('Y-m-d',$formatedStart);
                $str2 = date('Y-m-d',$formatedEnd);
                $date_from = strtotime($str1);
                $date_to = strtotime($str2);
                $date_to = ($date_to - 86400); // Fix the extra day issue
                    for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
                        $exclusions .= date(',"Y-m-d"', $i);
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    if ($google_ical_link != '') {

        $ical2   = new ICal($google_ical_link);
        $events2 = $ical2->events();

        if (is_array($events2) || is_object($events2)) {

            foreach ($events2 as $event2) {
                $formatedStart2 = $ical2->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event2['DTSTART']);
                $formatedEnd2 = $ical2->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event2['DTEND']);
                $strr1 = date('Y-m-d',$formatedStart2);
                $strr2 = date('Y-m-d',$formatedEnd2);
                $google_date_from = strtotime($strr1);
                $google_date_to = strtotime($strr2);
                $google_date_to = ($google_date_to - 86400); // Fix the extra day issue
                    for ($i=$google_date_from; $i<=$google_date_to; $i+=86400) {
                        $exclusions .= date(',"Y-m-d"', $i);
                    }
            }

        }

    }

    if ($booking_dot_com_ical_link != '') {

        $ical3   = new ICal($booking_dot_com_ical_link);
        $events3 = $ical3->events();

        if (is_array($events3) || is_object($events3)) {

            foreach ($events3 as $event3) {
                $formatedStart3 = $ical3->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event3['DTSTART']);
                $formatedEnd3 = $ical3->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event3['DTEND']);
                $str1_priceline = date('Y-m-d',$formatedStart3);
                $str2_priceline = date('Y-m-d',$formatedEnd3);
                $priceline_date_from = strtotime($str1_priceline);
                $priceline_date_to = strtotime($str2_priceline);
                $priceline_date_to = ($priceline_date_to - 86400); // Fix the extra day issue
                    for ($i=$priceline_date_from; $i<=$priceline_date_to; $i+=86400) {
                        $exclusions .= date(',"Y-m-d"', $i);
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    if ($homeaway_ical_link != '') {

        $ical4   = new ICal($homeaway_ical_link);
        $events4 = $ical4->events();

        if (is_array($events4) || is_object($events4)) {

            foreach ($events4 as $event4) {
                $formatedStart4 = $ical4->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event4['DTSTART']);
                $formatedEnd4 = $ical4->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event4['DTEND']);
                $str1_homeaway = date('Y-m-d',$formatedStart4);
                $str2_homeaway = date('Y-m-d',$formatedEnd4);
                $homeaway_date_from = strtotime($str1_homeaway);
                $homeaway_date_to = strtotime($str2_homeaway);
                $homeaway_date_to = ($homeaway_date_to - 86400); // Fix the extra day issue
                    for ($i=$homeaway_date_from; $i<=$homeaway_date_to; $i+=86400) {
                        $exclusions .= date(',"Y-m-d"', $i);
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    return $exclusions;
```

}

Comment: So, what else have you done in profiling? Have you checked whether the file is large (which leads to long parsing times)? Have you checked whether loading the data over the network is slow?

Comment: Plus 1 on the large file.  Open the ics file in a notepad editor.  Are there old, and old recurring events?   Is there a way to request the ics file with future events only?   are you doing multiple at the same time? try cacheing the ics url locally - maybe the fetch is being throttled?

Comment: Hi Nico. The files is 22KB. Yes, the data loading times are otherwise good

Comment: Hi Anmari. Yes I'm parsing 4 iCal links at the same time